# Creating binary without main() function in embedded environment

Tags: c, makefile, linker, embedded

I need to create some project for MCU on c language, which does not have main() function. This project should be compiled and linked. Functions from this projects can be called by pointer, which should have fixed address.
I'm using Eclipse-based IDE for this and GCC toolchain.

For example:

```
/* linker script SECTIONS: '.fun1 0x601f1000 : {KEEP(*(.fun1))}' */
int (* fun_ptr)(int) __attribute__((section(".fun1")))  = &fun;
int fun(int a)
{
    return a*2;
}

int res
void main (void)
{
    int (* fun_call_ptr)(int) = (int (*)(int))(*(int*)0x601f1000);
    res = (*fun_call_ptr)(10);
}
```

The goal is to have function 'fun' in one project and 'main' in another. Then build both projects and load both binary files to flash separately.

I guess it can be done by some linker script or makefile, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The snippet shown has `main`. Sounds like you are asking about a library.

Comment: All embedded systems have a start address - that is basically the main.

Comment: @cup the OP has not suggested otherwise, he simply wants to call a function in one separately linked image with no entry point, from another image that has the entry point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The OP is asking that the function(s) be separately linked and loaded ( like a BIOS for example).  That is not the same as a statically linked  library.  That said it is possible that this is an X-Y problem and that there are other solutions to whatever it is the OP is ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @cup Very few if any embedded systems have main() as a start address. The vast majority has a power-on reset vector as starting point, from where the "C run-time" sets up clocks and memory. When everything is ready to go, it calls main().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not specifically done what you describe, but have done similar things, and the approach I would try would be:

- Compile the code with `-nostartfiles` so that no start-up code is linked (which is what causes `main()` to be called.
- Set an alternate entry point with the `--entry=` option so it does not need a `main()`. Alternatively just provide a dummy `main()` since with `-nostartfiles` nothing will call it.  The actual `entry` can be any function or a dummy function. Since there is no start-up code, nothing is going to start it.  It is just to satisfy the linker.
- Specify all functions (and other symbols) that you want to force to be linked even if not referenced by using the `--undefined=` linker option.
- Make all functions and symbols you want *external linkage* (i.e. not `static`) to prevent the *compiler* from discarding unused functions.

You should then get a fully linked binary that is a collection of functions that need not be explicitly internally referenced.

You could then use the emitted symbol map or `nm` output to determine the function entry point. However that requires that your image with the `main()` entry point must be built after the nostartup image, and re-built every time the nostartup image changes, obviating any advantage of having a separate image.  Instead I suggest that you create a single array of function pointers to each entry point, in a *fixed order* and locate that table at a specific location (i.e. a vector table).  Then you use that to lookup function entry points by index into the table.  That way you may also not need multiple `undefined` linker options for each separate function, but a single one for the table, and either image can be updated independently, so long as the indexes do not change.

There may be other considerations, but that is the general approach to take I think.

Comment: `-ffreestanding` does not necessary mean "discard start-up code". It mostly means discard silent inlining of standard library calls into the machine code, but also that the form `void main (void)` is expected. gcc can only discard whatever libs that it is aware of, and on most embedded systems that just means the standard lib, not the "CRT". If running bare metal x86 with a gcc/Linux compiler, well that's another story.

Comment: @Lundin. Changed "freestanding" for "no start up" which I think addresses your valid point.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way by far is to handle this with two different code bases, developed individually but linked together, sharing the same linker script. Then you can just create a custom section for the functions and that's it. You could for example have 3 IDE projects, one for each code base and one for linking/debugging debugging them together.

If they need to be kept apart because one is a bootloader and one is the actual program, you can still do that with the above setup, just erase the previous code through the bootloader.

If linked together, then you don't need to use function pointers - just ensure that function inlining is disabled and verify by checking the disassembly. It also eases problems with calling convention if functions are called directly.